# Render HTTP Response(HTML content) in selenium webdriver(browser)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module to send `GET` and `POST` requests to websites and then processing their responses. If the `Response.text` meets a certain criteria, I want it to be opened up in a browser. To do so currently I am using `selenium` package and resending the request to the webpage via the selenium webdriver. However, I feel it's inefficient as I have already obtained the response once, so is there a way to render this obtained `Response` object directly into the browser opened via selenium ?

**EDIT**
A hacky way that I could think of is to write the `response.text` to a temporary file and open that in the browser. Please let me know if there is a better way to do it than this ?

Comment: short answer no. Long answer, there are hacky ways like what you are trying but why bother? What do you gain by all that effort?

Comment: @e4c5 as I said, I want to open a page response in selenium only if it meets a certain set of conditions in its response, if I simply open up all the requests in browser that would make my application slower due to the unnecessary responses that the browser will be rendering

Comment: Why are you opening in a browser?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham to check for XSS execution, the code tries to inject alerts as a proof-of-concept RXSS and then checks in the browser for it successful execution.

Comment: Have you tried [`selenium-requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium-requests/)?

Comment: @JRodDynamite yes I tried `selenium-requests` but that doesn't seem to be working as expected, there isn't proper rendering within the browser, moreover it opens and closes new tabs instead of working in the current tab.

Answer (score 14):

To directly render some HTML with Selenium, you can use the data scheme with the get method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

content = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/").content

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + content)
```

Or you could write the page with a piece of script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

content = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/").content

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_script("""
  document.location = 'about:blank';
  document.open();
  document.write(arguments[0]);
  document.close();
  """, content)
```