# Render series of responses in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to collect a series of responses when navigating a website, and afterwards "recreate" the process **using the responses**.

From an [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785588/render-http-responsehtml-content-in-selenium-webdriverbrowser) I found this solution to render HTML:

```
content = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/").content

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + content)
```

Unfortunately, when I try this (using Firefox instead of Chrome), the content is simply put into the browser address bar.

How can I render a series of responses, including for example XHR-responses with selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution, or rather workaround. When saving requests (urls) and responses in a dictionary, you can set up a server that answers each request with its resprective pre-recorded response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for certain browser-specific things, like the fact that [`#` and `%` have to be escaped if you use Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239272/771848) - from what I understand, you can simply pass the content through `quote()`:

```
try:
    from urllib import quote  
except ImportError: 
    from urllib.parse import quote # if Python 3

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + quote(content))
```

No need to do that if you use Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! But can I also process all other requests that way? Just as if the browser would send requests, and would receive dummy-responses - without having to send requests. I want to feed responses, and see the browsers behavior.

Comment: @Peter1807 not sure, could you please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve and why do you need a real browser instead of, say, using just `requests`? Thanks.

Comment: I want to test client-side frameworks. The server responses contain templates in those cases, that are only rendered in the browser. I want to see how altering these templates affects the resulting page.

Comment: @Peter1807 okay, but can you use `driver.get()` to get to the templates directly, without intermediate `requests.get()`?

Comment: I would collect the responses from another source. So I would not need to use requests.get()